# Pulling from database on button click SWIFT UI

Tags: swift, firebase, swiftui

I have a create post function that adds a document to my firebase database and I am trying to fetch it and display it to the user on the front end when the post has been successfully added. The way I'm trying to do this is fetching changes on click of a button, but because the function to create a post is in the same button they execute at the same time (before the post has been successfully created) and ends up not showing the newly created post.

How would I do this - would it be a completion handler or state variable change or?

CODE BELOW:

```
                            Button {
                                viewModel.uploadPost(withCaption: caption)
                            presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                            showAlert.toggle()
                            viewModel.fetchposts()
        
                        } label: {
                            Text("Post")
                                .bold()
                                .padding(.horizontal)
                                .padding(.vertical, 8)
                                .background(Color(.systemBlue))
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                                .clipShape(Capsule())
                        }
```

Comment: Are you saying the user writes a post, you take that post and store it in Firebase, and then read it back in to display to the user that just wrote it? If so, why do that? The data is already in memory so just display it without the additional read. If not, can you elaborate a bit on why that's being done?

Comment: @Jay Good point, I've been trying to figure out how to do that. Could you help?

Comment: Well, there's really not enough code in the question to know exactly what's going on but in general, your UI is pulling data from a source - often times an array. My suggestion is to write the data to Firebase, and then add it to the array, which SwiftUI will probably refresh the UI to show that new data.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the upload posts and fetch posts are getting called at the same is because you are using asynchronous way of calling the methods. Instead, wrap the callbacks inside a `Task` struct. It will allow you wrap and use `await` to run asynchronously. Or you could also wrap them in different `Task` instances and call them using `await`.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
 var body: some View {
   Button {
     Task {
       await uploadPost()
       await fetchPosts()
     }
   }
 }
}
```

[Documentation for Task](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/task)

Comment: This didn't work, unfortunately.